# Linking a form to backend API on AppDrag

Tags: forms, content-management-system, cloud

So I started working on this CMS called AppDrag, (it's kinda like a Squarespace but for developers, where you like have access to the source code of all your elements) has anyone used it yet?  I'm a bit stuck trying to figure out how to make a form call an API from my backend.  I dragged an input field into my page and it doesn't give me the option to trigger it to my APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had a hard time with that at first.  You actually have to make sure you're dragging in a **Cloud Backend Input**, and not a standard **Form Input**.  Then in your triggers, select Cloud Backend, and make sure to check "Enable".